# Get the type of file of a Media Server URL (no extension) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I have a file being served by a Media Server and therefore the URL has no file extension, how can I use JavaScript to find out what the extension actually is?

For example, lets say this is my url:

/MediaServer?MediaID=SomeRandomMediaIDWithoutExtension

I would like to use JavaScript to determine what type of media resides at that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the response header. For exemple :

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:'/MediaServer?MediaID=SomeRandomMediaIDWithoutExtension',
   success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
   }
  });
```

[Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

Or use Content-Disposition header. Wish returns possibly returns you filename. (Thanks yo @bhspencer)

As you said you'r looking for **SRT** / **VTT**

Those two files are formated differently so you could compare first lines of your file to determine his format.

Comment: Why are you using POST? Which header do you think is likely to contain the media type?

Comment: I guess you should use HEAD instead of GET, to avoid downloading the whole file if it's large.

Comment: But he wan't to download the file ?

Comment: You might also consider looking at the "Content-Disposition" header. Since that might reveal the file name with the extension.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to basically do what I want.  I am specifically trying to find whether the media is a vtt or srt.  My returned content type for those are text/plain.  Is there any way to get a bit more specific?

Comment: @jpsnow72 Have a look at the "Content-Disposition" header

Comment: Thanks, I posted that a second too soon. I will take a look